# How difficult would it be to add a generic code-gen backend to Julia?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, julia, crystal-lang

How difficult would it be to add a generic `code-gen` backend to `Julia` in the vein of `go` and `chez-scheme`i.e. without the LLVM.

Would LLVM be a better way to do it - given that `rust` and `crystal` are also almost entirely self hosted and they can leverage the LLVM to emit binaries, even cross compile.

For a background, I've asked a question specifically about `code-gen` in case of various LLVM front-ends here [What are the issues faced while implementing a self-hosted language on LLVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403804/what-are-the-issues-faced-while-implementing-a-self-hosted-language-on-llvm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rustc links and uses LLVM, both via the LLVM C API and via an [extended wrapper](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src/rustllvm) in C++, exposed as a C ABI. I don't know about crystal, but some languages do target textual or bytecode LLVM IR directly, which has some potential advantages, but also performance and compatibility issues.

As far as "how difficult": `NaN`, I guess? The most straightforward approach would be to start with Julia's [type-inferred](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/reflection/#Intermediate-and-compiled-representations-1) [lowered form](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/ast/), which is already close to [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form). Someone with a good compiler background could probably write an un-optimized (spilling, no code motion, etc.), one-architecture template assembler in a short time (~months). Someone with no compiler background would probably need a fair amount of study to properly formulate the question.

Answer (score 6):

Julia does have a form of code-gen which is its typed AST. You can see the typed AST using `@code_typed` in front of any function call. Theoretically you can use that to emit to any IR, and Julia chooses LLVM IR for reasons stated elsewhere. [Transpiler.jl](https://github.com/SimonDanisch/Transpiler.jl) is a package which does this to output things like OpenCL code from Julia functions.

You can use the LLVM IR to emit other bytecodes. [CUDANative.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDAnative.jl) uses LLVM's .ptx backend to emit CUDA kernels directly from Julia functions. The `@polly` project is looking to do similar things whereby the macro would allow Julia to auto-accelerate some codes on the GPU (I admittedly have little knowledge of this, [other than reading the post which suggested it](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/gsoc-17-proposal-enabling-julia-to-target-gpus-through-polly-and-imrpove-code-using-run-time-information/2872) and [the followup](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/rfc-optimizations-using-run-time-information-for-polly/3807). This was picked up as a GSoC project for LLVM).